# Formatting JSON datetime to PHP inside foreach loop

Tags: php, json, api

I am building an event section for a client. Using JSON and PHP, I'm able to pull in all the data perfectly.

What I'm having trouble on is formatting the date correctly inside the foreach loop. Currently I've set it to get today's date for now, but I know that's pointless as each event shows today's date.

Here's a sample of the structure code:

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Skrillex/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=SAMPLE");
$data = json_decode($json);                                      
$datetime = new DateTime();                              

foreach($data as $events) {
    echo "<td class='bit-venue'>" . $events->venue->name . "</td>"; 
    echo $datetime->format('M j, d');
}
?>
```

I know I'm missing something, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Working solution:**

Got it working.

I changed `$datetime->format('M j, d')` to `date('M j, d', strtotime($events->datetime))`

I knew I needed to invoke the `datetime` string, but just was not sure how to go about that in the foreach loop.

Credit goes to Bilal who's answer disappeared for some reason.

Comment: Can you give the example of your $json string?

Comment: Yes, you can view the link http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Skrillex/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=SAMPLE and it should show you the datetime string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code should be like this

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Skrillex/events.json?   api_version=2.0&app_id=SAMPLE");
$data = json_decode($json);                                      
$format = 'Y-m-dTH:i:s';                              

foreach($data as $events) {
    echo "<td class='bit-venue'>" . $events->venue->name . "</td>";

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $events->datetime);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

?>

Comment: For some reason it was giving me an error, but I figured it out. Thank you!